# Why does changing Inner html in JavaScript cause Default action even if calling evt.preventDefault();?

Tags: javascript, html, file, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a drag and drop system where I have a file imput that takes a file dropped on a div and sets it as a value for a `<input type=file>` element:

```
 <div>
        <div id="dropContainer" style="border:1px dashed grey;height:16vh;">
            <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="thumbnail" style="display:none; z-index:0"/>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="thumbnail-drop-text" style="margin-top: -9.5vh; margin-bottom: 7vh; z-index:1; text-align:center">
        <small> hey </small>
    </div>
   <script>
    dropContainer.ondragover = dropContainer.ondragenter = function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    };

    dropContainer.ondrop = function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        fileInput.files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
        //document.getElementById('thumbnail-drop-text').innerHTML = "<small>hello</small>";
    };
</script>
```

this code should prevent the default action (opening the image file in the browser) which it does. now I want to test if it worked and therefor uncommented `//document.getElementById('thumbnail-drop-text').innerHTML = "<small>hello</small>";`

When I did that he browser returned to doing normal behavior (as if there was no `evt.preventDefault();` in the code)

Why is this? how do I fix this?

Comment: i tried the same code it is working fine ie image is not opening in browser. can you post the full script, how you getting dropContainer?

Comment: This is the full script... There was an answer here but it got deleted... Funny enough I managed to read it before it was deleted and it worked for me

Comment: i think that solution will not work. You need to create div with `contenteditable=true` and attach your listener to this div.

Comment: That's what the answer said before it got deleted...

Comment: yes, but it was for another condition. you have input type file also, so i misssed to read it that time. So you create a div with contenteditable property and attach you event here, and it input type file will also work with this, If this work for you i will make it as answer :)

Comment: wait could you write an answer so I can undertand better what you mean?

Comment: is the answer works for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to on `designMode` of element before dropping any image or other stuff into this. Try with this code and see in console after drop image.

```
var dropContainer = document.getElementById('dropContainer');
dropContainer.ondragover = dropContainer.ondragenter = function(evt) {
  dropContainer.designMode = "on";
  // dropContainer.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
  console.log('hover');
  evt.preventDefault();
};

dropContainer.ondrop = function(evt) {
  console.log('drop');
  evt.preventDefault();
  fileInput.files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
  dropContainer.designMode = "off";
   // dropContainer.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
  //document.getElementById('thumbnail-drop-text').innerHTML = "<small>hello</small>";
};

dropContainer.dragend = function() { // if user drop outside of droppable area.
   // dropContainer.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
  dropContainer.designMode = "off";
}
```

Comment: I've fixed it with .removeAttribute("contenteditable") on the dropContainer. Is that the same?